# Compare two arrays and check for duplicates and missing values

Tags: java, arrays, function

I have a String Array x with the words: chair ,table, couch

I have a second Array y with the words: chair, spoon, table, knife, couch, towel

I want to check if all the words in x are used and also that the words from x are not used twice in y for example:  chair ,spoon, table ,knife ,couch ,towel ,chair, fridge In this example chairs is used twice.

My approach is to use a for loop the size of y and then go trough every other index because the values of x are always going to be in that order, and create a test case array , but I do not know how to check if all the items of x are used and to check if they are not used twice

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < y.length; i+=2){
    test[i] = x[i];
}
```

Comment: Suppose you only have a single word to worry about, not a whole array of words. How would you solve that?

Comment: You say "*then go trough every other index because the values of x are always going to be in that order*". If you already know how values from `x` are placed in `y`, why do even need to compare?

Comment: The two standard solutions are 1) sort the arrays before comparing, 2) employ a Map (perhaps of the counting variety) to keep track of what elements have and have not appeared.

Comment: A good approach to this problem is to incorporate both `recursion` and `memoization` into your program. Not only will it be as optimal as can be but it will also operate on a dynamic level.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a map to store your results. For example:

```
    Map<String, Integer> counters = new HashMap<>();

    for(int i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {  // Why do you use i+=2?
        String sY = x[i];

        if (counters.contains(sY)) {
            counters.get(sY)++;
        } else {
            counters.put(sY, 1);
        }
    }

    for(Don't know the type... counter, counters) {
        if ( counter.value() > 1)
            throw new IllegalStateException("You used " + counter.key() + " " + counter.value() + " times. Thats too much" ); 
    }
```

Please notice that this code will never compile, but I hope, you got the Idea.